# Is it legal to copy a design in a Youtube video?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, youtube

I'm thinking about making a Youtube video in which I would model in 3D the design from a 2D game and 3D print it.
Would I be allowed to do that, without having to ask the permission to the designer of that game ? (I wouldn't share the 3D file though, that would be illegal for sure).

And what about if the video is monetized ?

I see many videos on Youtube in which people recreate protected designs in 3D - as for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeoGINB8CHA) that is a tutorial to recreate an *Among Us* character - but do not know if this is legal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be considered a derivative work and therefore require permission from the copyright holder.

In many cases, fanart such as the 3d rendering in your example is ignored because it the publicity is beneficial to the creator. This is entirely the copyright holder's perogative however.